# How to test functionality using unit test if flow is event based in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am writing a unit test for a flow which is event based. Let me tell you the complete flow with code. I have a application App1 which send some commands(one way) to App2. Then App2 sends events after some time as response. Not clear?
Let's simplify it. I have a App1 which allows user to select some goods and after complete selection, user reserved the selected goods so that no other user can select these goods. To reserve the goods, App1 sends commands to App2 to reserve goods one by one. If there are 3 goods, then App1 sends good1 to App2 to reserve, when event received from App2, App1 sends next good2 to reserve and again the process continues until all goods reserved. I have already implemented this functionality and now time to write unit test for it but not sure how can i handle it. Too much text, lets see some code.

```
 public void ReserveGoods(List<Goods> items)
        {
            //Goods recived from GUI;
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                var item = items.First();
                //_agent is nothing but a class to communicate with App2
                _agent.ReserveGood(item.SectNo);
                //After this method, On GUI the status of process is pending unit the else part not run.
            }
            else
            {
                NotifyToGui(Response.GoodsReserved);
            }


        }

        //Event recived from App2
        private void ReadyToProcessNextGood(object sender, ReadyToStartNewGoodItemEventArgs e)
        {
            var processId = e.ProcessId;
            //Remove reserved good.
            _ItemRepository.Delete(e.SectNo);
            var items = _ItemRepository.GetGoodsByProcessId(processId);

            //Going to reserve remaining items
            ReserveGoods(items);
    }
```

I want to write unit test for this flow. I can mocked the _agent.ReserveGood(item.SectNo) method like i invoke the event ReadyToProcessNextGood but after invoked, how can get into ReadyToProcessNextGood event.

Answer (score 1):

I would split this into two parts.

1. test the business functionality, with unit tests / integration tests as appropriate
2. test the whole thing with integration tests.

The way I would do it is like this:

first break down the code even more to remove the events part from it. something like :

```
 private void ReadyToProcessNextGood(object sender, ReadyToStartNewGoodItemEventArgs e)
    {
            //maybe some checks here to make sure you have the right data
            BusinessMethodHere(e.processId, e.SectNo);
    }

public void BusinessMethodHere( string processId, string sectNo )
{
            //Remove reserved good.
            _ItemRepository.Delete(sectNo);
            var items = _ItemRepository.GetGoodsByProcessId(processId);

            //Going to reserve remaining items
            ReserveGoods(items);
}
```

Now you have a way to test the business functionality separately, outside from an event call.
Keep decoupling your business stuff and test properly.

Finally create an integration test which actually relies on an event and make sure it flows through the system properly. At that point you don't need to test business functionality because you've already done that with unit tests / other integration tests.